# Get an array from a string of numbers separated with comma

Tags: lua

How can I convert a string like `s = "6.1101,17.592,3.3245\n"` to numbers in Lua.

In python, I usually do

```
a = s.strip().split(',')
a = [float(i) for i in a]
```

What is the proper way to do this with Lua?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is fairly trivial; just do a repeated match:

```
for match in s:gmatch("([%d%.%+%-]+),?") do
  output[#output + 1] = tonumber(match)
end
```

This of course assumes that there are no spaces in the numbers.

Comment: Using `s:gmatch("([^,%s]+)")` is probably more robust and also allows whitespace. On the other hand, this pattern will extract any "words" between commas, not just numbers.